# Write a record count to a variable in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I'm a newbie to Shell script requirement is need to get  row count from a flat(.txt) file and assign to a int variable.

Trying this but not working

```
FNAME="pn_data_"$month$day$year".txt"
   declare -i recordcount=0
      for f in $FNAME
     do
       recordcount+=`wc $f |'{print $1}'`
     done
```

Any suggestions around would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick with `wc` is that if you supply a file name on its command line, it prints it in the output.  To avoid that, feed it standard input.  The RHS of the `|` symbol is weird — maybe you missed out `awk` in front of the action?  But it is overkill: you can simply write:

```
declare -i recordcount

recordcount=$(wc -l < $FNAME)
```

(And I'd not normally bother with the `declare` line.)

Note that I'm assuming that you have just one file and need the record count from the one file.  If you need to process multiple files and get the aggregate count, then you either need to process each file separately in the shell and do arithmetic on the value from `wc`, or you run `wc` on all the files and let it print out the total number of lines at the end (which can be post-processed with `sed` or `awk` to get just the number from the last line of output).

Comment: @Jonathan: thanks it is working but what is the return value of the command if there are no records.. if no records I've to assign it to  recordcount = 0..how to do that...

Comment: If I run `wc -l < /dev/null`, I get zero; what do you get?  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Jonathan: yes it answers my question..I'm getting empty..i will try with  recordcount=$(wc -l < $FNAME) < /dev/null

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: \n is not working in the follwoing code but it works for the first 4 words but not from fifth though..any idea?   \nStatus = File transfer failure \nFile name = ${FNAME} \n Date/Time attempted = $(date)\nRecord count = ${recordcount} \nError that occured : Other \n cause: error

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Not working for the last 2 words, ie \nError that occured : Other \n cause: error

Comment: If you do `recordcount=$(wc -l < $FNAME) < /dev/null`, the `wc` command is reading from `$FNAME`, not `/dev/null`; the `/dev/null` redirection is doing nothing useful in that construct.  I'm trying to make head or tail of your bigger comment, but I can't work out what's going on from the comment.  I suggest editing your question, adding a new section at the end after a `<hr>` line that describes the extra problem.  Then 'ping' me by adding a comment here that you've done so.  We should probably clean up this comment trail once you've seen that I've responded to your amended question.

Answer (score 0):

```
FNAME="pn_data_"$month$day$year".txt"
for f in $FNAME
do
  recordcount=$(expr $recordcount + $(wc -l < $f))
done
```

Comment: Thanks Perrel for quick response.